# How do I call an object of a class that inherits another class that has arguments in its constructor?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, g++

I am working with multiple classes and files, so I have created this dummy code to better define my problem. I have a parent class `Parent` and a child class `Child`. I've separated both of these in a .h and a .cpp file

**parent.h**

```cpp
class Parent
{
    Parent(int a, int b, int c);
    protected:
        void somefunc();
         
};
```

**parent.cpp**

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "parent.h"

Parent::Parent(int a, int b, int c)
{
    std::cout<<"Answer is: "<<a+b+c;
}
void Parent::somefunc()
{
    std::cout << "I am some func";
}
```

**child.h**

```cpp
#include "parent.h"
class Child : public Parent
{
    public:
    void funk();
};
```

**child.cpp**

```cpp
    #include"child.h"    
    void Child::funk()
    {
        somefunc();
    }
```

And I'm using another file `running.cpp` to run this.

```cpp
    #include "child.h"
    int main()
    {
        Child a;
        a.funk();
        return 0;
    }
```

Trying to build this using g++, gives me the error:

```
running.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
running.cpp:4:11: error: use of deleted function ‘Child::Child()’
     Child a;
           ^
In file included from running.cpp:1:0:
child.h:2:7: note: ‘Child::Child()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Child : public Parent
       ^~~~~
child.h:2:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Parent::Parent()’
In file included from child.h:1:0,
                 from running.cpp:1:
parent.h:3:5: note: candidate: Parent::Parent(int, int, int)
     Parent(int a, int b, int c);
     ^~~~~~
parent.h:3:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
parent.h:1:7: note: candidate: constexpr Parent::Parent(const Parent&)
 class Parent
       ^~~~~~
parent.h:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
parent.h:1:7: note: candidate: constexpr Parent::Parent(Parent&&)
parent.h:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

The g++ command I'm using is `g++ *.cpp -o test`

I understand that I'm somehow supposed to give arguments to run the constructor of Parent, but I'm not sure how to do that.

1. How do I get rid of this error?
2. If the error is unrelated to this, how do I make an object of a Child Class when it is inheriting a class that has arguments in its constructor? I need to invoke the argument constructor as well, so I can't just make another blank constructor and use that instead.

Comment: You declare the `Child` constructor function, but where you do define (implement) it?

Comment: The error tells you that you declared `Child::Child()` but you did not implement it.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I was testing something by myself and didn't revert correctly before making the post. Edited the question!

Comment: It's still the same problem, just moved up a step: You declare the `Parent` default constructor function, but you never define (implement) it.

Comment: Still that basic mistake. Changed once more

Comment: Now the question is drastically different from the original question, making comments and (worse!) *answers* irrelevant. Please don't update like that. Make sure that the [mre] you show us really replicates the issue you want to actually ask about from the beginning. Having to respond to a moving target will put of many potential helpers.

Comment: As for the *current* problem you need either a `Child` default constructor that invokes the parementerized `Parent` constructor. Or add a `Parent` default constructor. Or alternatively pull the paremeterized `Parent` constructor into the context of the `Child` class, and construct `Child` objects using arguments.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've given a heads up to the person that answered as well. Yeah the error changed, but the gist of my query is still the same. I'm not used to actually posting on here.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't rush your questions, take your time with them, improve them while writing, or even discard a question if you feel it's not good enough and start over with a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get rid of this error?

You can **solve** this error by adding the default constructor in class `Parent` as shown below. Also, note that you need to make the constrcutors **`public`**.

**parent.h**

```
class Parent
{   public: //ADDED PUBLIC KEYWORD
        Parent(int a, int b, int c);
        //ADD DEFAULT CONSTRCUTOR
        Parent()=default;
    protected:
        void somefunc();
         
};
```

Comment: Which will then need to call the constructor of `Parent`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I was testing something by myself and didn't revert correctly before making the post. Edited the question!

Comment: Still that basic mistake. Changed once more

Comment: @VisheshVarma Why are you changing your question again and again?

Comment: Yeah that was an oversight as well just like my previous edit. I've changed the question once more!

Comment: @VisheshVarma I have edited my answer according to your edited question. Check it out.